# Manual SQL install error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am receiving the following error when trying to manually install my SQL:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host' at line 1
```

The following are the first few lines of my SQL code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2014 at 08:53 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.24
-- PHP Version: 5.3.13

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Did you copy/paste that SQL code from a web page?  If so, ensure it's encoded in plain ASCII and that the `-`'s are really `-`'s and not some other character. Perhaps just try removing all those comment (`--`) lines. Also, in your bottom commented lines, you forgot to include the semi-colon within the comment, so you have 4 extra semi-colons that may be messing with it.

Comment: The -'s appear to be true -'s as they are original in my SQL file from my template. Where would I want to add the semi-colon? I have not edited this SQL from its original as of yet.

Comment: I'm suggesting you remove the semi-colons.  Since `/* */` are in-line comments, then `/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;` = `;`. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. Still seeing the exact same error message.

Comment: Did you try removing all the commented lines at the top? the error seems to be suggesting it thinks the first like 5 lines are a single line.  this is why I suggested ensuring that the `-`s were really `-`s, and that you try removing all those lines starting with `--`.

Comment: Just tried that as well. Same error still. hmm

Comment: If you removed those lines then there's no way the error would be exactly the same (since it mentions those lines in it ;) ). Please edit your question and include the exact error returned after removing those lines.

Comment: The odd thing is that the error code is not changing. I removed the /* */ and also the semi-colons. Perhaps since the error is "at line 1" it is getting caught immediately at the start. I do not see how, though.

Comment: No.. Forget about the bottom lines for now. Remove the top ones.; the ones that start with '--'

Comment: Tried that and got a bunch of new errors.